# .NET Counterpart For The Scripting.DLL

Tags: .net

We were using Interop.Scripting.Dll reference in our VB.net project.

We do not want to use this Interop.Scripting.Dll in our VB.Net project now.Can we get the .Net Counterpart of Scripting.Dll so that we do not require to build our .Net project with the old scripting dll reference?

We are using Scripting.FileSystemObject,Scripting.Folder,Scripting.TextStream,Scripting.File and Scripting.IOMode.ForWriting of Interop.Scripting.Dll.What is the equivalent .net counterpart of these objects in VB.Net 2010?

It would be great if any help will be provided.

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0):

A little Googling turned up a [discussion](http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/vb-net-general-discussion/19311-interop-scripting-dll-net-noob.html) that suggested the functionality in this DLL could be replaced by [`System.IO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx) classes. The functionality is probably spread out a bit among different classes. [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) and [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) are used for reading/writing text files. You may also find [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) and [`Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) useful for managing files and folders. [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) is great for path manipulation. With these classes, you'll usually be using strings for paths instead of having an object.

Basic Tutorials for reading and writing files:

- [How to: Write Text to a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx)
- [How to: Read Text from a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx)

Hopefully, that's enough to at least get you started. Good luck.

Comment: No problem. If these classes are what you're looking for, I'd appreciate if you could accept this as the answer. (You do that by clicking the check box next to the answer.)